# When finding files using CSOM, do folders improve performance?

Tags: development, csom

I know that, as a general rule, [metadata should be used rather than folders](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20use%20metadata%20instead%20of%20folders%20in%20sharepoint&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) in SharePoint.  However, I haven't found anything that discusses the benefits of metadata over folders when it comes to finding files using `CSOM`.

I have a library that stores files that are associated with a non-SharePoint web form that pertains to customer feedback.  I only need to find the existing files for a specific customer, or add new files for that customer.

If I have a library with 5000 files, and I want to find all files where `Company = "Some Value"`, the inspection (either in `C#` or in SharePoint as it implements `CAML` filters) must iterate over all 5000 files in the library to find the result set.

If, however, I structure the files so that there is a folder for each company, then I can easily find all files where `Company = "Some Value"` by setting the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` and returning all the items the folder contains.

```
public void DisplaySharepointFiles(string folderUrl = null, int parentFolderId = 0, int level = 0)
{
    var sourceList = ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibrary.Title);

    if (folderUrl != null)
    {
        Query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folderUrl;
    }
    ListItemCollection items = sourceList.GetItems(Query);
    ClientContext.Load(items);
    ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    List<SharepointItem> folderList = new List<SharepointItem>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var spItem = CreateSharepointItem(item, parentFolderId, level);
        if (spItem.IsFolder)
        {
            folderList.Add(spItem);
        }
    }
    //do some unrelated stuff

    //subfolders & files
    foreach (var sItem in folderList)
    {
        DisplaySharepointFiles(sItem.ItemPath, sItem.Id, level + 1);
    }
}
```

### **Question**

In light of my use case, are there benefits to avoiding folders and using metadata for locating specific files in a library using `CSOM`, or are folders less expensive in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

As a high-level thinking on algorithms, the deeper the *tree* is, the longer the crawling algorithm is expected to run at least when compared to one-dimensional structure. If you know the "Company" as in your case, sure you can narrow the crawled content, but wouldn't the same apply if it's just a metadata, which can also be fetched with CSOM?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of objects that must be inspected.  I believe (and correct me if I'm wrong), using FolderServerRelativeUrl eliminates the need to inspect any objects.  I immediately know that everything below that "node" is what I want to display.  If I don't set FolderServerRelativeUrl, all objects must be inspected to determine whether Company metadata = "Some Value".  Or is my impression incorrect?

Comment: @devlincarnate I see what are after. Unfortunately I can't tell the truth basing it on any citation at least. It seems to come down to the point whether the complexity of getting the folder by its name + returning all results is more effective than crawling a source where the items match a certain metadata. The complexity levels shouldn't be equal, so there's might be a point where one is faster and on another one slower. Probably to find the answer to your case, you'd need to do tests with both setups.